# Module not found error when importing a Flask app in unit testing

Tags: python, unit-testing

I'm trying to write a unit test for a Flask app with only one endpoint. When I ran the api normally and test with Postman, everything works perfectly. However, when I tried to import the app with `from api.my_api import app` in my `my_api_test`, everything just breaks.

Here's the structure of my project

```
my_project
    - api
        - my_api
    - test
        - my_api_test
    - config.ini
    - ...etc...
```

This is the log of the error

```
============================= test session starts ==============================
collecting ... ERROR: not found: /Users/me/dev/my_project/test/my_api_test.py::TestEndpoint
(no name '/Users/me/dev/my_project/test/my_api_test.py::TestEndpoint' in any of [<Module my_api_test.py>])


my_api_test.py:None (my_api_test.py)
../venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pytest/runner.py:341: in from_call
    result: Optional[TResult] = func()
../venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pytest/runner.py:372: in <lambda>
    call = CallInfo.from_call(lambda: list(collector.collect()), "collect")
../venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pytest/python.py:531: in collect
    self._inject_setup_module_fixture()
../venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pytest/python.py:545: in _inject_setup_module_fixture
    self.obj, ("setUpModule", "setup_module")
../venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pytest/python.py:310: in obj
    self._obj = obj = self._getobj()
../venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pytest/python.py:528: in _getobj
    return self._importtestmodule()
../venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pytest/python.py:617: in _importtestmodule
    mod = import_path(self.path, mode=importmode, root=self.config.rootpath)
../venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pytest/pathlib.py:567: in import_path
    importlib.import_module(module_name)
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.13_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py:126: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1050: in _gcd_import
    ???
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1027: in _find_and_load
    ???
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1006: in _find_and_load_unlocked
    ???
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:688: in _load_unlocked
    ???
../venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:186: in exec_module
    exec(co, module.__dict__)
predict_test.py:7: in <module>
    from api.my_api import app
../api/my_api.py:19: in <module>
    config = Config().get_config()
../api/config.py:18: in __init__
    config_model = config['MODEL']
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.13_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/configparser.py:965: in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
E   KeyError: 'MODEL'
collected 0 items / 1 error
```

In the first line it's saying that my test file doesn't exist. I have made sure that `__init.py__` exists in every folder. The funny thing is without the `from api.my_api import app` this error never occured. So I'm sure something's wrong with this `from api.my_api import app` itself... Any help is appreciated.